# remove image tag with empty src

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have image tags in my html that have empty src attributes.
This causes bugs in different browsers.
I would like to remove all the image tags that have empty src dynamically

Html:

```
<div class="newsroom-item"> 
  <article> 
    <figure> 
      <a href="/content/NewsRoom/648408.html"> 
        <img src="" alt="" data-blog="" data-list=""> 
      </a> 
    </figure> 
  </article> 
</div>
```

I need help with the Javascript:

```
var figure = $('.newsarticle-list #newsarticlelist .newsroom-item figure a img');

$("figure[src='']").each(function () {

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use jQuery `remove()`:

```
$("img[src='']").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way

```
$('.newsarticle-list #newsarticlelist .newsroom-item figure a img[src='']').remove();
```

or if you want to use the object array.

```
figure.filter(function(){
    if(this.src == '')
       return $(this);
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean:

```
var figure = $('.newsarticle-list #newsarticlelist .newsroom-item figure a img');

$("img[src='']",figure).remopve();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use remove() on img with src='' inside figure tag

The code could look like this:

```
$("figure img[src='']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".newsroom-item figure a img[src='']").remove()
});
```

Comment: Correct it will load after your Document is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all image tags which src attribute is empty, you can use

```
$('img').each(function(index,element){
     var $el = $(this)
     if($el.attr('src') == '')
          $el.remove()
})
```